# Cannot read property 'sPath' of undefined error while performing .read() method

Tags: sapui5

I am confused with the error I get while trying to do .read() method of the odata model.

Here is my model definition:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/destination/sap/opu/odata/sap/ODataServer");
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "odata");
```

Here is the relevant method:

```js
_read: function(aFilters) {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel("odata");
    console.log("oModel",oModel);
    oModel.read("/myEntitySet", {
        filters: aFilters,
        success: function(oData) {
            console.log("oData",oData);
        },
        error: function(oError) {
            console.log("oError",oError);
        }
    });
}
```

The model is defined and is displayed in console.
In the line where the .read() method is, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sPath' of undefined

I have never seen such behavior before. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass filter parameter in OData read method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520045/how-can-i-pass-filter-parameter-in-odata-read-method)

Answer (score 2):

I had an error in my `aFilters` array. Well,the problem was that `aFilters` wasn't array at all. After fixing this issue, the `.read()` method worked fine.