# How can I pass filter parameter in OData read method

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need to pass a parameter in my OData.

The URL has to be like this:

```
http://my_gateway_system:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_TRANSF_APPROVAL_SRV_02/ztest_nameset('RUBENS')
```

Below is my code:

```
var sServiceUrl = "http://<my_gateway_system>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_TRANSF";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true, "username", "password");

var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();     
oModel.read("/ztest_nameset('RUBENS')", null, null, true, function(oData, response) {
    oJsonModel.setData(oData);
});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJsonModel);
```

When I past the URL

```
http:// my_gateway_system:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_TRANSF_APPROVAL_SRV_02/ztest_nameset('RUBENS')
```

in my browser, it works. But when I run my code, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the legacy method call of ODataModel#read (with the parameters spread out). The current signature for this method is `read(sPath, mParameters)`. Please check out the documentation of the method: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read

In your concrete case, you should do something like:

```js
oModel.read("/ztest_nameset('RUBENS')", {
   filters: [/* your filters here */],
   success: function(oData) {
      oJsonModel.setData(oData);
   }
});
```

Nevertheless, it is not clear what filter parameter you want to pass. In your example, you have no filter. The `/ztest_nameset('RUBENS')` URI is just a plain entity set + key. It is also not clear what errors you get. I could guess that it can be a [CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). You seem to be making the OData calls to some other host than the one you are serving the UI5 app from.